# Pulling a SELECT query into a datatable and accessing it

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, datatable

I'm writing a small ASP.net C# web page and it keeps giving me an error stating:
There is no row at position 0.

I'm probably doing it wrong but here is some of my code:

```
string SqlQuery = "SELECT * ";
    SqlQuery += " FROM main_list";
    SqlQuery += " WHERE ID = @FindID";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=???;database=contacts;User          
    ID=???;Password=???;");
    conn.Open();

SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, conn);
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FindID",searchID);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);

    try {
         da.Fill(dt);

         fillData(p);
    }
    catch {
         txtId.Text = "ERROR"; 
    }
```

And FillData is the following:

```
protected void fillData(int pos) {

    txtId.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["ID"].ToString();
    txtCompany.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Company"].ToString();
    txtFirstName.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["First_Name"].ToString();
    txtLastName.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Last_Name"].ToString();
    txtAddress1.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Address1"].ToString();
    txtAddress2.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Address2"].ToString();
    txtCity.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["City"].ToString();
    txtState.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["State"].ToString();
    txtZipCode.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["ZipCode"].ToString();
    txtPhoneNum1.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Phone_Num"].ToString();
    txtPhoneNum2.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Phone_Num2"].ToString();
    txtFax.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Fax_Num"].ToString();
    txtEmail.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Email"].ToString();
    txtNotes.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Notes"].ToString();
    txtCategory.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["Category"].ToString();
    txtSubCategory.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["SubCategory"].ToString();
    txtDateAdded.Text = dt.Rows[pos]["DateAdded"].ToString();
    txtDateModified.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DateModified"].ToString();

}
```

Here is the call that errors out:

```
protected void btnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    p--;
    lblPage.Text = p.ToString();
    fillData(p-1);

}
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    p++;
    lblPage.Text = p.ToString();
    fillData(p-1);
}
```

I'm trying to cycle thru the Rows[0] to Rows[1] or however many there is but it gives me the error about no row at position 0 or position 1. It only fills once and then errors out.

EDIT:
I'm trying to access the second row returned by the database after already accessing one row already. For example: Rows[0] is accessible fine but then when I try to read Rows[1] it errors and says it doesn't have a row in position 1. I can revise the code to return Rows[1] and it works but when I try to access Rows[0] it breaks. This is why I pass the variable (p) to fillData so it can show only that Rows value. Thanks!

EDIT 2: I believe it's because there is a postback that wipes the values retrieved by the database. Is there a way to get the database entries to stay even after a postback? If not I am guessing I will have to query the database every time.

Comment: What means "It only fills once and then errors out"? Why should it fill more than once?

Comment: "however many there is" - Are you trying to iterate all the rows?

Comment: Run in debug mode and see what happens when you try to pull data from database and if datatable is filled. Maybe you aren't getting any data from database

Comment: I'm trying to create pages.  So it first fills with Rows[0] or Rows[1] but when I try accessing it a second time, it gives the no row in position error.

Comment: are you calling the entire code you have above twice?  If you are, you're probably errorring out because the connection isn't being closed.  If not, show us how you are incrementing p

Comment: i'm calling fillData everytime. That is it.

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates there are no rows being returned by SQL. Are you sure there is data to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `dt.Rows[0]` you are effectively saying "take the first row that comes back, and get a value from it."  If the DataTable doesn't have any rows (i.e. your SQL query returns no matches), that's like saying "Here is a plate that contains no apples.  Take the first apple and tell me what colour it is" - see?  Doesn't make sense.

What you should do is check whether there are any rows before you try to read them...

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // do stuff here.
}
```

Comment: dt.Rows[1] should be the second row. The count is 2 and I can't access the second row after I've already accessed the first.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq and a stored procedure it is much nicer

```
datacontext context = new datacontext();

var result = context.MyStoredProc(searchID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: How do you set a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
    SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FindID",searchID);
```

to

```
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindID",searchID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your query on your database, make sure rows are actually being returned.  Also, it's bad practice to put your query directly into your code like that, especially when using parameters.  You might want to try something like this:

```
private Int32 CallStoredProcedure(Int32 FindId)
{
    using (var dt = new DataTable())
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SEL_StoredProcedure", conn))
            {
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindId", FindId);
                    sqlCmd.Connection.Open();

                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            return Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["ID"]);
        else if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            throw new Exception("Multiple records were found with supplied ID; ID = " + studentId.ToString());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To set up your stored procedure, on your database run this:

```
CREATE  procedure [dbo].[SEL_StoredProcedure]

@FindId int = null  
as
SELECT * FROM main_list where ID = @FindId
```

Comment: How do you I set the stored procedure?

Comment: Okay! I'll try that. My main problem however is that the returning query has more than 1 row and I want to cycle through them. I edited my question a little.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove the index identifier from the code:

e.g.

```
txtId.Text = dt.Rows["ID"].ToString();
```

Comment: -  `DataRowCollection` does only have one indexer, the one which takes an integer specifying the index of the `DataRow` in the `DataTable`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.item.aspx